# Change text objects with core data objects

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I need to substitute the row content from a tableView. In this case, the rows are populated from a a switch loop. I want to change the text objects with objects from a core data entity. I show you the two implicated methods: :

```
//cellForRowAtIndexPath    
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) 
        {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        }

        // Configure the cell.

        switch (indexPath.row)
        {
            case 0 : cell.textLabel.text = @"First Cell"; break;
            case 1 : cell.textLabel.text = @"Second Cell"; break;
            case 2 : cell.textLabel.text = @"Third Cell"; break;
            case 3 : cell.textLabel.text = @"Fourth Cell"; break;
            case 4 : cell.textLabel.text = @"Fifth Cell"; break;
            case 5 : cell.textLabel.text = @"Sixth Cell"; break;
            case 6 : cell.textLabel.text = @"Seventh Cell"; break;
            case 7 : cell.textLabel.text = @"Eighth Cell"; break;
            default : cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell %i",indexPath.row + 1];
        }

        //cell.detailTextLabel.text = ...;

        return cell;
    }
```

And

```
//NSFetchedResultsController:

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                   entityForName:@"ToDoItems" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                              initWithKey:@"tdText" ascending:NO];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =
    [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                        managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                   cacheName:@"Root"];
    self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    return _fetchedResultsController;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a new project in Xcode using the **Master-Detail Application** template and then check the **Use Core Data** checkbox on the next dialog, you will get all the boilerplate code you need. For example:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}
```

and

```
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSManagedObject *object = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [[object valueForKey:@"timeStamp"] description];
}
```

PS. I think it's better to name your entity "ToDoItem" instead of "ToDoItems", don't use plural in this case

Comment: Thank you, I will check your answer.